# Adding Strings to An Array

Tags: objective-c, c

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

BOOL isChecked; 

//check if there is checkmark there

if([tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath].accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark){

    isChecked = YES; 

}

else {
    isChecked = NO; 
}

//adds or moves checkmark

if(isChecked == YES){

    NSLog(@"Checkmark removed...");



    UITableViewCell *newCell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    newCell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone; 

    lastIndexPath = indexPath; 

}


if(isChecked == NO){

    NSLog(@"Checkmark added...");

    [chosenSports addObject:[sports objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]]]; 

    NSLog(@"%@",[chosenSports objectAtIndex:0]); 

    UITableViewCell *newCell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath]; 
    newCell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark; 

    lastIndexPath = indexPath; 

}


[tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
```

}

For some reason the result of my NSLog is NULL, indicating that the "chosenSports" array is empty, but I don't know why! Any suggestions?

Comment: If your array was really empty, this would actually crash and not log `null`.

Comment: @omz, in Objective C there is no NullPointerException...compiler returns random garbage from memory if the pointer points to null valued address. So it won't crash, it will keep runing

Comment: @Owl I know, that's why it's actually not crashing (the array is `nil`, not empty). But trying to get the first object of an empty array _would_ raise an exception.

Comment: @omz, My bad, apologies! I didn't understood at first time. Peace!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you initialize your array like so (in your viewDidLoad function):

```
self.chosenSports = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWith...];
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your array is an instance of NSMutableArray.  If that is done correctly, then you know that `[sports objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]]` is evaluating to zero (nil/NULL).  Try querying the array for its count.